# How to change download behavior?

Tags: javascript, download, v8, puppeteer

I am working on JavaScript website to extract all anchor's absolute URL using puppeteer, but in some cases there is anchor's have download function to download documents and i just want absolute URL without download it

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="downLink(0, '/somepath/download.ashx?id=102');">Download</a>

<a class="text" href="javascript:openDatasheetDownload('/procatalaog/Datasheet.jsp;jsessionid=3901737BA7133?productId=(%5bsaui,j430000%5d)', 'PDF DATASHEET', 'width=300,height=500,resizable=yes,menubar=yes')">Download</a>
```

and if we try catch the absolute URL like normal we will just catch for example something like this 'downLink(0, '/somepath/download.ashx?id=102' as the URL

so i have an idea that if we can change chromium V8 download behavior to just redirect it without download it so we can create wok around to catch these URL 's